# How to open existing flutter project from Xcode?

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, visual-studio-code

[image: Could not open file]

I have an existing flutter project, which coded with VS Code. Now I want to open it from Xcode to do some configurations in `Runner.xcworkspace`. But it was unable to open the project from Xcode and it shows the above warning. So, how can I open my existing project from Xcode now?

Comment: You can delete all pod related autogenerated files(podfile.lock, Pods folder, Runner.xcworkspace), Then run "flutter pub get" and "pod install" from ios/ path. It will generate all the deleted files again. Now try to open it. It should work. If still not, then something wrong with XCode. Please have a look here, 
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120972

Answer (score 29):

If you want to make changes in the `Runner.xcworkspace` and you are using VSCode, I would suggest you open the project in VSCode and Right-Click on the `ios` folder.

Here you will see an option: Open in Xcode.

Select that option and the iOS project of the Flutter project will open in Xcode and you can carry on with the changes as you want

One thing to note is that like **Android Studio**, **Xcode** is not supported for Flutter Development as of now so if you try to open the whole project it will not let you.

Answer (score 14):

Note! Unlike Android studio, flutter isn't supported to XCode yet, you have to open iOS folder of Flutter project only and solely.

**1-** Open XCode

**2-** Select 'Open existing Projects'

**3-** Search your project through search bar in window or search manually through directory.

**4-** From your Flutter Project, open the iOS folder.

And here we go! You have opened it.

Answer (score 8):

I successfully open the `AppFrameworkInfo.plist` file with Xcode as follows.

1. Open the project with Android Studio
2. Select the **iOS > Runner** folder
3. Navigate to **Tools > Flutter > Open iOS Module in Xcode**

Answer (score 0):

How I solved,I deleted the Ios folder and then run`flutter create .` and then just change and add what you want.